# Change Character Direction While Jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer and I followed a tutorial to build my character. This character works fine except that when jumping, it doesn't allow for changing direction midair. How can I add to this to make my character able to change direction mid-jump?

The code used for the basic movement is below:

```
void Update()
{

    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if(controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection.Set(rotation, 0, 0);
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        //running code
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)) //check if shift is held
        { running = true; }
        else
        { running = false; }

        moveDirection *= running ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed; //set speed

        //jump code
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump();
        }
    }

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);


}
```

EDIT: Forgot to include the code for jump(), that's probably kind of important...

```
 void jump()
{
    moveDirection.y=jumpHeight;
    transform.parent=null;
}
```

Comment: what is the code in `jump()` ?

Comment: Oops! Edited the question.

Comment: Just a guess; exclude the definition of `moveDirection` from the `if` block. Perform that before it. So: `moveDirection.Set...; moveDirection = ...; if(controller.IsGrounded)`.

Comment: Oddly, this prevents the character from jumping very high. It only just gets off the ground, and then is pushed back to the floor again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you de-parent your transform?

Comment: Wow, that's a leftover from an attempt at moving platform support (it works now and shouldn't need that) and I didn't even notice when I pasted it here.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the `moveDirection` vector only when the character is grounded:

```
if(controller.isGrounded)
```

when player jumps `isGrounded` is set to false, so `moveDirection` won't be updated (except for gravity).

I suppose you don't want to affect the velocity of the character while is jumping (unless it is supposed to fly or walk in the air). I guess you want to change its orientation while it's jumping, so you can directly modify transform making it rotate accordingly to your input.

Something like:

```
else
{
   float amountOfRotation = Input.GetAxis("...") * rotationScaleFactor; 
   transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.up, Time.deltaTime * amountOfRotation);
}
```

---

EDIT

I've never used it but I think CharacterController is designed for being moved only when the object is grounded. So if you want to move it while it's on the air, don't use the Move method but edit directly the transform of your GameObject:

```
else
{
   float additionalForwardSpeed = Input.GetAxis("...") * speedScaleFactor;  
   transform.Translate(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * additionalForwardSpeed ); //translate
}
```

the code above should increase the speed of your object in local forward direction.

Comment: I actually don't want the character to rotate at all. I don't necessarily want it to walk in the air, but I'd like if it could slightly change its direction while in the air, in case of an accidental jump. Think of a Mario game (2D platformer), he's able to move in the air slightly.

Comment: @rar: ok..than simply move it instead of rotate it inside the else statement.

Comment: Adding   `else
  {
   moveDirection.Set(rotation, 0, 0);
   moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
  }` just makes it go back to the ground immediately after jumping.

Comment: You're correct that CharacterController is not designed to move in the air. But the translate you provided moves me in the z direction. I'm not sure how to change the forward direction, but why would I always want it to be forward? The jump I've written allows me to jump in a certain direction, I just can't change that in the air at all.

Comment: @rar: mine was just an example. Try to understand the idea and then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Well I've tried and tried, but everything ends up with some weird issue. Is it really that hard to modify the code I have to have him able to move in the air?